# Flash Drive Won't Format or Mount on PC or Mac

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, flash, format

I just purchased a 3-way 128GB flash drive from China.  My Mac won't recognize its existence, and my Windows 7 SP1 machine won't mount it but it is visible in device manager and admin tools.  I've tried to format it on my PC but it constantly fails...

Please help.

Comment: Are you able to see it in disk management on your Windows?

Comment: If you ask nicely, they will not only sell you a "3-way 128GB flash drive", but even a bridge in New York. Just throw it away, it's "fake flash"

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Start > CMD "Run as administrator"
2. Type the following command:

   diskpart
3. Then:

   list disk
4. Be very careful here! Know your USB number.
5. Type the following command:

   select disk #
6. Change # with your USB number.
7. Type the following command:

   clean

**You’ll see a “diskpart succeeded in cleaning the disk” if everything worked properly! check if your USB work now!**